# How to remove duplicate characters when combining two strings in shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, duplicates

I have 2 strings and I want to combine them and remove duplicates.

Example:

```
str1=/home/username
str2=/home/username/project
str3=$str1+$str2
```

Result:

```
echo $str3
>> /home/username/project
```

How do i provided it like str3?

Comment: My thought is, the premise of your question is highly likely to be wrong. The fact that you want to do this means you probably already have gone off track. Then again, who knows, requirements are many and varied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in facility for this. If you know that `str2` may or may not contain `str1` as a prefix, you can exclude it with a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
str3=$str1${str2#"$str1"}
```

The quotes are necessary to guard against shell metacharacters in the pattern; for example, `${foo#*}` removes everything from `foo` whereas `${foo#"*"}` only removes a literal asterisk if present.

Comment: Does this work if str1 may or may not contain str2, or does it only work if str2 may or may not contain str1? The original poster is asking a poor question, but taken literally it has to do both.

Comment: This is only for exactly the case in the first paragraph.